# RAW HTML Module inside Custom Module Hubspot

Tags: javascript, python, module, hubspot

I want to add a custom field or module (raw_html) in the Hubspot custom module, which is not present in Hubspot custom module by default. Anyone here can guide me that how can I can custom field (raw_html) or any textarea type thing in Hubspot custom module.

Basically,  I have a video embedded code in form of javascript, which I am adding in the editor but when I add it in the editor it removes javascript URLs. As you can see in the screenshot.
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: How you create the HTML using Template Builder or Coded files?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution which might work-

1. You can create a module in Hubspot, Add the HTML code on the HTML part and then create a separate JS file and link that JS file onto this module.
2. Similarly you can also create a HTML file in Design manager and it should allow you to add JS code in the same way a normal HTML page allows, or you can create a separate JS file and provide the link of that JS onto that HTML file.
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJP7E.png)